# How to implement if before while

Tags: c#

My code goes like this:

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader tx = null;

        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            tx = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            tx = new StreamReader("new.txt");
        }

        string line;

        while ((line = tx.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string url = (line);
            string sourceCode = Worker.getSourceCode(url);

            MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(sourceCode, @"title may-blank "" href=""(.+?)""", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            MatchCollection m2 = Regex.Matches(sourceCode, @"(?<=tabindex=\""1\"" \>| tabindex=\""1\"" rel=""nofollow"" \>)(.+?)   (?=<\/a>)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

            List<string> adresy = new List<string>();
            List<string> nazwy = new List<string>();

            int counter = 0;
            foreach (Match m in m1)
            {
                string adres = m.Groups[1].Value;
                adresy.Add(adres);

                counter++;
                label1.Text = counter.ToString();
            }

            int counter2 = 0;
            foreach (Match m in m2)
            {
                string nazwa = m.Groups[1].Value;
                nazwy.Add(nazwa);
                counter2++;
                label2.Text = counter2.ToString();
            }

            listBox1.DataSource = adresy;
            listBox2.DataSource = nazwy;
        }
    }
```

I am using RegEx to scrape text from web pages. And the thing is, that I want to scrape single URL if that URL is in `textBox1`. But if `textbox1` is empty, I want to scrape all the URL's from `new.txt` file.

So... I have to implement "if" but I don't really know how to. I mean, it should go like this:

```
if textbox1 is empty
then read from single line
if not, then read from new.txt
do stuff like scraping..
```

But as you can see in my code which is upper, it doesn't work properly. I mean it works, but only if I read from `new.txt`. When I add some text to `textbox1.Text` and try to scrape URL, my app is crashing. I assume that it crashes, because I shouldn't have used `streamreader` to read from `textbox`. I don't know. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your code like this, then you can use a `StringReader`:

```
TextReader tx = null;

if (textBox1.Text != "")
{
    tx = new StringReader(textBox1.Text);
}
else
{
    tx = new StreamReader("new.txt");
}
```

Make sure to wrap your code in a try/finally block and call `tx.Dispose()` in the finally.

Comment: Oh yea, it works. But have you any idea how to make something like += with listBox? I mean after every while loop my listBox is reseting, because old data is overwritten insted of adding new data. I cant do something like that:
       `listBox1.DataSource += adresy;` Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @audiophonic Store `adresy` in a property (to keep the value between each call), or cast the value of `DataSource` back to `List<string>`, or call `listBox1.Items.Add(...)`

Comment: When i did something like this:  http://pastebin.com/xJnMSEVu i have the same ListBox2, but different ListBox1. Do you know why?